# C# scoring based on answers

Tags: c#

I have some data that has values in properties called Poll_1, Poll_2, Poll_3, ...Poll_8.

I need to get a score based on this criteria:

For each Poll_1 thru Poll_4 that is not empty, FirstPollCount is incremented.
For each Poll_5 thru Poll_8 that is not empty, SecondPollCount is incremented.

This is currently how I'm doing it.

```
int pass1 = 0;
int pass2 = 0;
if (rec.Poll_1.Trim() != "") { pass1++; };
if (rec.Poll_2.Trim() != "") { pass1++; };
if (rec.Poll_3.Trim() != "") { pass1++; };
if (rec.Poll_4.Trim() != "") { pass1++; };
if (rec.Poll_5.Trim() != "") { pass2++; };
if (rec.Poll_6.Trim() != "") { pass2++; };
if (rec.Poll_7.Trim() != "") { pass2++; };
if (rec.Poll_8.Trim() != "") { pass2++; };

aa.FirstPollCount = pass1;
aa.SecondPollCount = pass2;
```

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: These type of questions is better suited on : http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Well, it didn't deserve the downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really any better, but if you want to look to an alternative

```
List<string> firstPolls = new List<string>()
{
   rec.Poll_1.Trim(), rec.Poll_2.Trim(),rec.Poll_3.Trim(),rec.Poll_4.Trim()
};
int pass1 = firstPolls.Count(x => x != "");

List<string> secondPolls = new List<string>()
{
   rec.Poll_5.Trim(), rec.Poll_6.Trim(),rec.Poll_7.Trim(),rec.Poll_8.Trim()
};
int pass2= secondPolls.Count(x => x != "");
```

By the way, what is the class for the *rec* variable? Probably an improvement is to add a internal method that executes this code and returns the value:

```
int pass1 = rec.GetFirstScoreCount();
int pass2 = rec.GetSecondScoreCount();
```

thus hiding the implementation details (the Trim() != "") from the client code that uses the rec variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq:

```
string s1 = "Random String";
string s2 = "Random String";
string s3 = "Random String";
string s4 = "Random String";
string s5 = "Random String";
string s6 = "";
string s7 = "Random String";
string s8 = "Random String";
int countPool1 = (new List<string>(){s1, s2, s3, s4}).Count(t => t.Trim() != "");
int countPool2 = (new List<string>() { s5, s6, s7, s8 }).Count(t => t.Trim() != "");

Console.Out.WriteLine("Pool 1 : " + countPool1);
Console.Out.WriteLine("Pool 2 : " + countPool2);
```

With output:

> Pool 1 : 4
>
> Pool 2 : 3

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Linq Query Syntax:

```
List<string> pol1to4Coll = new List<string>() { rec.Poll_1, rec.Poll_2, rec.Poll_3, rec.Poll_4 };
List<string> pol5to8Coll = new List<string>() { rec.Poll_5, rec.Poll_6, rec.Poll_7, rec.Poll_8 };

int countPol1to4Coll = (from poll in pol1to4Coll
                        where poll != ""
                        select poll).Count();

int countPol5to8Coll = (from poll in pol5to8Coll
                        where poll != ""
                        select poll).Count();
```